# Easiest way to animate QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qpropertyanimation

I want to animate a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` in my `QGraphicsScene`, with `QPropertyAnimation`.

```
QPixmap pixmap(filePath);
QGraphicsItem *pixmapItem = graphicsScene->addPixmap(pixmap);

QPropertyAnimation animation(pixmapItem, "x"); // here lies the problem
animation.setDuration(30000);
// ...
animation.start();
```

I checked the doc, so I already know that `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and its parent `QGraphicsItem` are no `QObject`, and that a `QPropertyAnimation` constructor with a `QGraphicsItem` does not exist. According to various sources, the best way is to create a new class, e.g. `AnimatedGraphicsItem` which inherits from `QObject` and `QGraphicsItem` OR I can simply inherit from `QGraphicsObject`.

```
class AnimatedGraphicsItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem // or public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem) // not needed if I inherit from QGraphicsObject, right?
};
```

What do I need to include exactly in the header and source files of my `AnimatedGraphicsItem` class? One source told me to include this in the header file too, but I thought, this is already inherited?

```
public:
    AnimatedGraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);

private:
     virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;
     virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
```

And how do I have to use my `AnimatedGraphicsItem` class?

Do I have to cast my `QGraphicsItem *pixmapItem` to `AnimatedGraphicsItem`? (If yes, how?) Do I have to create a new instance of `AnimatedGraphicsItem`?

I haven't found a good example on the Internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it.

I had to instantiate my `AnimatedGraphicsItem` object, then `setPixmap`, `setFlag`, … and `addItem` to my scene (and it was important to use `new`).